# Iron golems attacking mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

***Iron Golems*** attack **unarmed** pillagers and **baby** piglins. These are passive mobs. Why are iron golems attacking these mobs? Is this intentional behavior, or is this a *bug*?

Answer (score 2):

Under [Iron Golem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem#Behavior), it is stated they will attack piglins on sight, as well as attack baby piglins. And under the entry for pillagers, it is stated that they'll attack unarmed pillagers too.

Answer (score 0):

Iron Golems are programmed to attack all mobs except for wolves, creepers, and overworld animals. So it is not a bug when they attack baby piglins or unarmed pillagers.

Comment: They do not attack striders and will attack animals if the animals attack them